# JSON reader Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

How can I read JSON file into more than one documents and save it in Mongo DB.
I have two models:

```
@Document 
 data class Person(val name: String){
@Id
 private val id : String? = null
```

And:

```
@Document
data class Floor (private var floorName: StoreyEnum,
                  private val roomNumber: String
                  private val personID: String){

@Id
private val id : String? = null}
```

I have JSON file in which I have fields to both models. Moreover I want connect this documents with "relation", how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) if it's on a JVM backend.

BTW, I don't quite get your purpose of making `id` `private`, `val`, and initialized to `null` at the same time. Because in that way it's always set to `null`, never changed and never read. so I changed it to this:

```
data class Person(val name: String, private val id: String? = null)
```

Then you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to encode and parse the object:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val person = Person("name", "0")
    println(person)
    val personJson = gson.toJson(person)
    println(personJson)
    val parsedPerson = gson.fromJson(personJson, Person::class.java)
    println(parsedPerson)
}
```

Output:

```
Person(name=name, id=0)
{"name":"name","id":"0"}
Person(name=name, id=0)
```